# How to use multiprocessing to import multiple scripts

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-import, python-multiprocessing

In my python project to load a page with multiple tabs, I have to first import each tab's script into the main script and each of the import takes 15mins or more. Below is the original code:

```
import tab_1
import tab_2
import tab_3

Main code below...
```

I tried to use multiprocessing as below but it didnt work:

```
def Import_tab1():
   global tab_1
   import tab_1

def Import_tab2():
   global tab_2
   import tab_2

def Import_tab3():
   global tab_3
   import tab_3

t1= multiprocessing.Process(target=Import_tab1)
t2= multiprocessing.Process(target=Import_tab2)
t3= multiprocessing.Process(target=Import_tab3)

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()

Main Code below...
```

I can see from print that the three tabs were importing successfully, but when I reached to main code and tried to access the tabs, I got the error message: NameError: name 'tab_1' is not defined.

Anyone can guide me on this?

Comment: Can anyone provide some clue...really in need of help! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Anyone can provide some help...really getting stuck on this:(

Answer (score 0):

Well you import inside a function/method , it works as intended.

Comment: I thought using global can make the import tab to be global? Because i need to use functions to do multiprocessing, or is there any other way to do that?

Comment: swap the import and global lines eg.
global tab_1 
import tab_1

Comment: ah yes I tried that too...but still didnt work